# How to understand the $\infty$-Wasserstein distance

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, matrix-norms

For two probability distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined on $X$, the *$p$-th Wasserstein distance* between the two of them is defined as $$W_p(\mu,\nu) = \left(\inf_{\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)}\int_{X\times X}c(x,x')^{p}\,\mathrm{d}\pi(x,x')\right)^{1/p}.
 $$

We also have $\infty$-Wasserstein distance defined as the limit of p-th Wasserstein distance, i.e., $$W_\infty(\mu,\nu) = lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} W_p(\mu,\nu).$$ However, I am having a hard time understanding this $\infty$-Wasserstein distance. We know $\infty$-norm is the element with the largest absolute value, for $\infty$-Wasserstein distance do we have such a simplification as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the discussion 5.5 in the book of Filippo Santambrogio "Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematician".
We can prove that the infinite wasserstein distance is given by
$$ W_{\infty}(\mu;\nu)=\inf \{ \lvert\lvert x-y\rvert\rvert_{L^{\infty}}(\gamma): \gamma \in \Pi(\mu,\nu) \} $$
where we have defined $\lvert\lvert x-y\rvert\rvert_{L^{\infty}}(\gamma)=\inf\{ m\in \mathbb{R} : \lvert x-y\rvert\leq m \quad \text{ a.e-} \gamma \text{ for }  (x,y) \}$.

It means that the infinite Wasserstein distance is the infimum of the infinite distance over transport plans from $\mu$ to $\nu$. I hope it answers your question.